Proof of limit interchange via Yoneda's lemma
The first step of the proof of
$$
\lim_{i \in I} \lim_{j \in J} F(i, j) \cong \lim F \cong \lim_{j \in J} \lim_{i \in I} F(i, j)
$$
(for $F : I \times J \to C$) in Riehl's "Category Theory in Context", theorem 3.8.1, says that it's sufficient to prove that
$$
C(X, \lim_{i \in I} \lim_{j \in J} F(i, j)) \cong C(X, \lim F) \cong C(X, \lim_{j \in J} \lim_{i \in I} F(i, j))
$$
"by Yoneda's lemma". But, doesn't appealing to Yoneda also require proving naturality in $X$, so that we could derive
$$
C(—, \lim_{i \in I} \lim_{j \in J} F(i, j)) \cong C(—, \lim F) \cong C(—, \lim_{j \in J} \lim_{i \in I} F(i, j))
$$
in $Set^{C^{op}}$ and reflect the isos back?
The reason I'm asking is that Riehl doesn't prove (or even mention) any naturality conditions here, and the naturality isn't immediately obvious from the proof of the isomorphism (at least, to me), so I'm curious if that's something that's implicitly left as an exercise to the reader, or if it's an obvious consequence of something else that I don't see?

Yes, naturality is required. Proving naturality is frequently not done (or mentioned) since it usually is more tedious than difficult.
